# CSS - best way for a drop-menu menu to have the same width as the parent

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

What is the best way for a drop-menu menu has the same width as the parent. Please HTML and CSS from below. Please also see https://jsfiddle.net/rd8Lq7dn/. I'm trying to find a solution that I don't need the specific the actual pixels in the width.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0;
}
.inline-menu,
.inline-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.inline-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.inline-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.inline-menu > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
}
.inline-menu > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="logo"></span>

  <ul class="inline-menu left-menu">
    <li><a href="">L-A</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">L-B</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give 100% width to the child.it will inherit the width of its parent.

```
.inline-menu > li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0;
}
.inline-menu,
.inline-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.inline-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.inline-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.inline-menu > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
}
.inline-menu > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="logo"></span>

  <ul class="inline-menu left-menu">
    <li><a href="">L-A</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">L-B</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```